# How to reinstall a repository pgp key?

Tags: updates, ssh, gnupg, signature

I have inadvertently deleted the key that allows for updating of the system, and now when I try updating using sudo apt update I get the following terminal output

```
Get:1 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release [3,949 B]
Get:2 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release [3,949 B]
Get:3 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release.gpg [455 B]
Get:3 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release.gpg [455 B]
Ign:3 file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release.gpg
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                       
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                                                                    
Hit:6 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease                
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:8 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user focal InRelease [166 kB]                                      
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                  
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [844 kB]                  
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [750 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                          
W: GPG error: file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E5231016A6508C17
E: The repository 'file:/var/lib/preinstalled-pool focal Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I reinstall the public key, given that the error message says it is unavailable? FWIW I have an additional laptop with the same OS installed, so perhaps I could copy the key from this?

Comment: This is a repository PGP key, NOT an SSH key.  Show the entire output of `apt update` because we need to see which repository is failing, usually this is a PPA or some other repository that is not the main repos.

Comment: @ThomasWard Done, as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has now been solved thanks to user dbergstein on the KDE forum at https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=170366.

The solution is quite simple:

```
apt-key export E5231016A6508C17 > key-data
```

on a machine that has the key installed, copy to the machine without the key, and then

```
sudo apt-key add key-data
```

where key-data is the name of the copied file.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect get the key from the other installed OS, in the directory for this.

```
zeus@buster-raspi:~$ ll /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ 
debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg            
debian-archive-buster-security-automatic.gpg   
debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg
```

Comment: I have tried doing this, but the problem still persists. However, the error message has slightly changed so I have edited the original question accordingly.